# AngularJS filter comparator seems not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got query results being loaded well, but when I try to filter them out by ID, filter not working. It just filters out all my objects so I have empty result. To debug it I've tried to add filter comparator function, but even if it returns true, result is empty. 
Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model='filterNum.id'/>
{{filterNum}}{{rentlist|filter:filterNum:fl}}
```

filterNum is my filter, rentlist is an array where the data loaded to, fl is the comparator function. Here's it:

```
$scope.fl=function(e,a) {
    console.log(e,a,e===a);
    return true;
}
```

Just wanted to see if the expected id and actual are equal. Here's what I see in debugger if I filter by id=14:

```
    3 14 false
    14 14 true
    17 14 false
....and there's many falses
```

Here's what I see on the page:

```
{"id":"14"}[]
```

You see? 14=14 and its true, comparator function returns true but I still get empty results. Did I missed something?

Comment: how does your rentlist looks like?

Comment: @Michael something like `[{"id":"3"...},{"id":"14"...},{"id":"17"...}...]`, its very long

Comment: please look at this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/n93RjIqLehVymmjjbTQd?p=preview it seems all works as you want. or there is something in your code that we can not see...